# Logstash script giving error

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

The given configuration is invalid. `Reason: Expected one of #, => at line 6, column 2 (byte 118) after`

```
input {
     file {
       path => ['/opt/logstash/logstash-tutorial.log']
       start_position => 'beginning'
       ignore_older => 0 2
       }
}
```

Putting double quotes in a string, gives the same error message.
I get the error at the sixth line of the code. Which is after ignore_older => 0 2  line.

Please help..

command executed by me to run the config file is `./logstash -f 'first-pipline.conf'`

Config

```
input {
     file { 
           path => ["/opt/logstash/logstash-tutorial.log"]
           start_position => "beginning"
           ignore_older => 0 2
        }
}
```

## The filter part of this file is commented out to indicate that it is

## optional.

```
filter {
     grok {
          match => {"message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"}
         }
 }

output {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`ignore_older` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-ignore_older) of the `file` input takes a number and `0 2` is not a number.

Fix that parameter like this and it will work:

```
input {
     file {
       path => ['/opt/logstash/logstash-tutorial.log']
       start_position => 'beginning'
       ignore_older => 0
     }
}
```